# ViewPager is calling transformPage() multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**Background :**

I have created infinite carousel using `ViewPager`. This carousel is displayed differently in `Landscape` and `Portrait` mode. Carousel rotation direction is Right to Left.

In Portrait mode, Carousel will show only one image. See below image. Here, `Image 3` is present on the screen. Black color frame is screen display area.
Other images are out of screen display.

[image: portrait mode]

In Landscape mode, Carousel will show three images. See below image. Here,
`Image 3` is fully present on the screen, while some part of the `Image 2 and Image 4` is present on the screen.

[image: landscape mode]

Now, I have my own `ViewPager.PageTransformer` for `ViewPager`. In this, I have override `transformPage(View view, float position)` function.

Default value for offScreenPageLimit is `1` for `ViewPager`. I have not changed this value. Now, In `Portrait` mode, While displaying Image-3, `ViewPager` will load Image-2 and Image-4. It will call `transformPage()` function ***three times*** because of offScreenPageLimit value.

**Problem :**

The problem is with `Landscape` mode. In Landscape mode, ViewPager is displaying three images : `Image-2, Image-3 and Image-4`. And It will load Image-1 and Image-5 because of offScreenPageLimit value. So, Ideally it should call `transformPage()` function for ***Five times***. But, It is calling it for ***SEVEN times***. WHY??

I also observed that order of calling the `transformPage()` function for SEVEN times is always same.

Order : called for Image-3, Image-2, Image-1, Image-5(`CALL-A`), Image-4, Image-5, Image-1(`CALL-B`)

Why does it get called for `CALL-A` and `CALL-B`? Because of this logic is written in `transformPage()` is not working correctly.

Can Anyone know why does it get called ***SEVEN times***??

Comment: Are you worried about performance or do you observe some incorrect behavior?

Comment: @Alex.F, Actually I am using position value of transformPage function which is coming incorrect